# GameCenter - Login user if they already entered their credentials

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit

In my game I don't want the GameCenter login popup appearing automatically when the app launches. So instead I have a GameCenter button that the user can tap to login with. When they press the button, the login screen appears.

However, it seems like when you launch the app again after logging in, the user still isn't "logged in". They still have to press the button again and then a little banner appears saying "Welcome back, User!". Is there a way to automatically relogin the user without them having to press the button each time? I already entered my credentials, why do I have to authenticate again?

Here is my code, when the user presses the button:

```
self.authenticatePlayer()
```

And here's the authenticate method:

```
    func authenticatePlayer() {
        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
            (view, error) in

            if view != nil {
                self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```

I need something that can welcome back the user if they already logged in, but NOT ask them to login if they haven't logged in already.

Comment: You can try saving name in userDefault at button click.and check to  see if your userDefault key has any username saved after you try to re-login.

Comment: @TusharSharma I'm a little confused by what you mean sorry. Just started using GameCenter today. I'm familiar with saving data though

Comment: i mwan to say when your user is getting logged-in you can save its status somewhere.And check it second time when you login again if its present then create your conditions accordingly.

Comment: Ah okay so this seems like a decent workaround. But what if they log out of GameCenter outside of the app, my app would still have them saved as logged in and then would prompt them to enter their login info on launch which I don't want.

Comment: Outside of the app means?

Comment: Like in the settings menu under GameCenter

Answer (score 2):

To understand the behavior you're seeing, we need to look at how the authentication process works.

It starts when you set the authentication handler. This is the signal that tells your app to try and talk to Game Center. The authentication handler's completion block has three possible conditions:

1. Error: something went wrong
2. Receives a view controller: the login view controller tells you the player isn't logged in
3. Receives nil view controller: the lack of an error + lack of a view controller tells you the player was already logged in.

Although IOS may be aware of your login state (or attempting to fake your login state using cached info), your app loses that context when you exit. When you startup again, there's been no attempt to set the authentication handler, thus no attempt to verify authentication status until your user presses the button, thus your app doesn't know whether the user is logged in or not.

I think the following approach will get pretty close to what you're looking for:

- set the authentication handler and initiate the authentication as early as possible in your first viewController's `viewDidLoad`. Do this as early as possible in your start up sequence.
- If the user isn't authenticated, you will receive a login view controller. Don't present it. Instead, save it. Don't present it unless/until the user presses the button.
- If the user is already logged in, they will see the welcome back message as soon as the game starts, and you'll be able to proceed since the user is still logged in.